# DbSetup simple example, SQLException occurs

Tags: java, integration-testing, sqlexception, dbsetup

There's very little information about `DbSetup` so I couldn't find an answer to this question anywhere else.
I need to test Data Access Layer and decided to use `DbSetup` for it. I tried to use [DbSetup user guide](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/user-guide.html#speedup-the-setup) this example just to see how it works but I get such exception:

```
com.ninja_squad.dbsetup.DbSetupRuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 127.0.0.1:3306
```

My database is MySQL Server. 
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is incorrect. JDBC URL for MySQL looks like

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename
```

as described in [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

And of course, the jar of the MySQL JDBC driver must be in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks! I had jdbc driver, but the url was wrong. Now it works.